# Is there any option to terminate the execution of query after 15 seconds?

Tags: java, timer, prepared-statement, executequery

```
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

I want to set timer exactly before the execute query for 15 seconds for that it should be terminated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this,

```
pstmt.setQueryTimeout(15);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: after that 15 seconds done I need to close this connection open other connection